# playing mp4 files in html5

Tags: html

I am trying to play a mp4 file from my server on google chrome. but nothing hapens when press play, it lights up for a split second (which shows the does exist) but then fails to stream. If I enable divx webplayer extension on chrome it plays it through divx player, however I need it to be possible to play it without that extention. here is the code I am using:

```
<video width="560" height="340" controls>
<source src="hood.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" '>
</video>
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173822/chrome-could-play-html5-mp4-video-but-html5test-said-chrome-did-not-support-mp4

In any event, that answer should help.

Comment: thanks for the link. I read it and saw that the problem was that chrome only play h-264 mp4 files not MPEG-4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semi-answer: try and use [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/) it plays pretty much anything and it automatically downgrades if needed. (Using HTML5 or Flash)