# video.js unexplained error

Tags: html, video.js

I have the following code:

```
<video id="v2" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
data-setup="{}">
<source src="uploads/5148dc022c494_183a658049ae973e1f3451450d689f39.wmv.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

I've implemented the relevant JS scripts at the `<head>` tag and I can see the player frame loading including the controls, however the video is not displayed.

When I check the console log I can see some sort of error, the only thing I can see is:

`Video Error 
_V_.Event {originalEvent: Event, type: "error", isDefaultPrevented: function, timeStamp: 1363730623374, vdata1363730622853: true…}`

I can unfold that message to view more details but nothing really tells me why the script fails.

The video itself is working when I download it. I can watch it with my windows media player without any issues.

Note: I'm using the latest Chrome version (tested IE10 as well, not working).

Comment: Maybe it's because chrome [doesn't support the codec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173822/chrome-could-play-html5-mp4-video-but-html5test-said-chrome-did-not-support-mp4).

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious reply would be to say that your video is not mp4 but wmv

either convert it to mp4 or use wmv type attribute

mind the extension which is currently .wmv.mp4