# video tag either used with flowplayer or without runs in firefox but not in chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, flowplayer

this code is sample by flowplayer.still its not working in chrome(only audio is playing).

```
<head>

   <!-- player skin -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skin/minimalist.css">

   <!-- site specific styling -->
   <style type="text/css">
   body { font: 12px "Myriad Pro", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; text-align: center; padding-top: 5%; }
   .flowplayer { width: 80%; }
   </style>

   <!-- flowplayer depends on jQuery 1.7.1+ (for now) -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <!-- include flowplayer -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

   <!-- the player -->
   <div class="flowplayer" data-swf="flowplayer.swf" data-ratio="0.4167">
      <video>
         <source type="video/mp4" src="..//sidvish/user/sid/gallery/videos/1372927564.mp4">

      </video>
   </div>

</body>
```

the video tag is working perfectly in firefox but not working in chrome.it only plays audio in chrome.what can be the reasons?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very known problem with Google Chrome

1. Enter “Chrome://flags” in the address bar.
2. Find an entry that says “Disable hardware-accelerated video decode.”
3. Click “Enable”.
4. Your videos should now play just fine

You could also try to do this: (this worked for me)

1. Type chrome://plugins click on +details find the PepperFlash entry
   and click Disable.Use only Adobe plugin.
2. Check your extension causes the trouble.Disable them one by one and
   check.

Now restart your Google Chrome

Hope it works :)

Here's a link to the original post: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/297tWaAYyGo/uCgzS-pv1isJ

Comment: i am creating a website and i cant say all my users to enable these plugins in chrome!

Comment: Some chrome browser do have it enabled. But it's a bug with Crhome and `.mp4` video's Either add a comment like "It could be that the video isn't playing right" or use other video's rather than .mp4

Comment: Also have a look at this answer for better understanding of the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12174154/1379394 :)

Comment: thnks .it works now.but can u tell any possible solution on how to enable these plugins directly from my websites code..??or give links to user to ask them to enable these

Comment: You can't change it in your websites code because it's a problem with Chrome. This problem is just a bug in Chrome, it will be fixed in the next release I hope. Don't forget to accept tho :)