# MP4 videos in Flowplayer does not play in Windows 7 Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, flowplayer

I have used the licensed version of FlowPlayer 5.3.2 to play an encoded video in mp4 format. In almost all the browsers it plays without any hiccup but it does not play in the latest version of Chrome 28.0.1500.95m (to date 13-08-2013) on Windows 7. I'm loading the player to the page upon a button click using AJAX. This happens only in Chrome for Windows. I am triggering the following function on a button click and pops up the light box and loads the player using AJAX inside it.

```
function playVideo() {
    var url1 = 'http://example.com/dashboard/play_video';
    var url = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx.mp4?413142680';
        $.ajax({
            url: url1,
            type: 'post',
            data: 'url=' + url,
            success: function(data) {
                var toolbox1 = $("#how_to_make_video").html();
                $("#video_preview2").html(data + toolbox1);
                $("#video_preview2").dialog({
                    width: 700,
                    height: 500,
                    close: function(event, ui) {
                        $(".flowplayer").stop();
                    }
                });

                if (url.indexOf("s3.amazonaws.com") !== -1) {
                    $(".flowplayer").flowplayer({splash: true,
                        rtmp: "rtmp://" + userStream + "/cfx/st",
                        swf: "/site/js/flowplayer/flowplayer.swf"
                    });
                } else {
                    $(".flowplayer").flowplayer({splash: true,
                         swf: "/site/js/flowplayer/flowplayer.swf"
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the same function that is used to play in all the other browsers. But when playing videos using this, the player shows an error "html5: Video not properly encoded" first and then automatically changes it to "html5: Video file not found". When the video URL "url" in above code is pasted in Chrome's address bar it does not play either. But it plays in other browsers on other platforms.

Is it a problem with the latest version of Chrome or the video?

Answer (score 2):

I would look at how your MP4 video is encoded as several formats of video and audio can be wrapped in an `.mp4` container.

There is a good post from Mozilla on [Media formats supported by HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) It states

> The MP4 container format with the H.264 video codec and either the AAC audio codec or the MP3 audio codec is natively supported by Internet Explorer, Safari and Chrome, but Chromium and Opera do not support the format.

Also this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12174154/1593273) states:

> Chrome can play .mp4 with H-264 video but not MPEG-4 Visual video.

If you want to cover all browsers you really need two formats, `MP4` and `WebM`

Comment: @Colin Bacon Your last sentence is incorrect! According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support), `MP4` format (with _any_ codec, including `H-264`) can't be played in Opera and `WebM` is not supported on Mac (not at all on iOS and partially on MacOS). Plus (previous sentence), MP4 video encoded with `MPEG-4 Part 2` (predecessor to newer `MPEG-4 Part 10 H-264` is out of HTML 5 specification, so not only Chrome, but none of the browsers support it.

Comment: @TechyTee Due to first error message ("_Video not properly encoded_") I would generally agree with Colin, that there are some problems with codec used to encode your files. First thing, you should consider is to get some sample videos, that are 100% sure to play without problems in any browser (YouTube, Flowplayer site itself, Google search for some demo HTML 5 video files, etc.) including Chrome. If you get some samples, then put them through your code to check if Flowplayer plays them. Then you'll know, if problem is up to Chrome or Flowplayer.

Comment: @trejder If you look at the Wikipedia link you provided, it shows that Opera does not support `MP4` but does support `WebM`.  This is why I have stated you need two formats to cover all browsers so if one is not supported the other is.

Comment: @ColinBacon Sorry, somehow my perception stopped at `MP4` part, put a dot (end sentence) there and completely ignored `WebM` part. Really strange, but stranger things happend! :] Of course, you're right. Having two formats doubles spaces taken by your video content on server, but does covers all modern browsers and devices.