# Display Video in html5 web

Tags: javascript, html, video, browser

I need to play a video in my web page. I used following code for test it.  Result  display player but won't play the video. I used updated chrome as my web browser.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<video controls=controls>
    <source src = "q.mp4" type="video/mp4"/> 
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Note- my video and the web page is contain in same folder.

I change the source as following

```
<video width="400" height="300" controls>
       <source src="video.m4v" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
       <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

Now webm file plays in my waterfox browser but same result on chrome and IE

Comment: Fixed little bit now video plays in chrome and firefox using webm. but bot work with IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try providing appropriate codecs for all the video files. Like this:

```
<video width="400" height="360" controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  <source src="video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
  <source src="video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Go to project folder and run the web page directly from browser to check it... If you use developing tools (like VS), debugging may not give the correct results

Answer (score 0):

Playing video is tricky, you can try this

```
<video width="400" height="300" controls>
  <source src="q.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <object data="q.mp4" width="400" height="300">
  </object>
</video>
```

The encoding of your mp4 file might not be supported by chrome
[chrome could play html5 mp4 video but html5test said chrome did not support mp4 video codec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173822/chrome-could-play-html5-mp4-video-but-html5test-said-chrome-did-not-support-mp4)

If above doesn't work you can try [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) It will try to play the video with html5 first then fall back to flash player.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this

use a J query Plugin Like video.js or go with HTML5

[here's the link](http://www.videojs.com/)

Comment: I downloaded video.js. there is a demo page if am i correct it should play the video but it has the same problem

Comment: Which Browser you are using Brother ? is it HTML5 Browser or not ? Can you Please Describe the problem for Video.js because video.js is working fine on my chrome and Mozilla Firefox