# Video stored on Windows Azure blob doesn't work with VideoJS (with Chrome)

Tags: windows, html, google-chrome, video, azure

I want to store .mp4 videos to display them in a HTML5 player (videojs).

I have a Problem on Chrome browser :  I can't moving seek-bar back or forward in the video (stored on Azure). This problem does not arise if I host the video on another server.

I have checked the mime type (video/mp4). Have You Encountered this problem?

Apparently it is possible that the problem comes from the Accept-Ranges: bytes (not present in HTTP response).

Here is the link in question: http://tbf.azurewebsites.net/fr/media/unrealistic-expectations-10000-dollars

Thank you very much,

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

Formats supported by Chrome are H-264, VP8 (WebM video part), Theora for video and MP3, AAC, Vorbis for audio. MPEG-4 Visual is not supported (Chromium issue 54036).

So, Chrome can play .mp4 with H-264 video but not MPEG-4 Visual video.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12174154/1384539