# Html5 Video isn't working

Tags: html, video

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head><title>Video</title>

<style type="text/css"></style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="Content"><br>
<video width="854" height="480"  controls="controls">
<source src="MyMovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
stuff
</div>

</body>
</html>`
```

When I view this on Google Chrome I get the video, but none of the buttons can be pressed and the video doesn't start.

Comment: are you sure Chrome supports that type of video?

Comment: I believe the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12174154/483536 Chrome can play .mp4 with H-264 video but not MPEG-4 Visual video. and there should be a closing </video> tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see the buttons, this is probably an issue related with your CSS.

To have the video start automatically, use the parameter autoplay="autoplay" ([parameters of HTML5 video](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)):

A demo of a working video in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WkprC/).

Working code:

```
<div id="Content"><br>
    <video width="854" height="480"  controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    stuff
        </video>
</div>
```

Answer by @Wayne: I believe the answer is here stackoverflow.com/a/12174154/483536 Chrome can play .mp4 with H-264 video but not MPEG-4 Visual video. and there should be a closing  tag.

Comment: The button are showing they just dont work. when i used your code but with my video file name it still didnt work heres the css code                 #Content{width:900px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color:452070;
list-style-type:square;}

Answer (score 0):

wrong doctype "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">"

HTML5 doctype is: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: I tried that. the only thing that happened was the color from the background disappearing. the video sill does not play

Answer (score 0):

add appropriate codecs as below: 
<source src="MyMovie.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>