# Adding .wmv-video to site with <video>-tags

Tags: html, .htaccess, video

It seems that i cannot add .wmv-videos to my site, though some ppl (in Google search) says it can an anothers say it cannot...
But i only have these videoes in .wmv-format and therefore have to put them on page in this format.

I have tried many things as:

```
<video id="sampleMovie" width="300px" height="168px" preload controls>
    <source src="video.wmv" type="video/x-ms-wmv" />
</video>
```

And also have i rendered my .htaccess

```
AddType video/x-ms-wmv .wmv
```

And also without the dot.
But what it tells me when i try to load the page with the video is:
"No video found with the supporting MIME-type"
(It says that on another language than english, so it might not be 100% correct, but the point should be there)

How can i make this work?

Comment: Also i can see (also by Google searches) that the best way is to have several versions of the same video though not all browsers supports the same videoformats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options.

**One:**

WMV files can play in IE with the Windows Media Player object. See [this](http://www.walkernews.net/2008/08/17/windows-media-player-how-to-embed-wmv-file-in-html-code/).

**Two:**

There is no way. No browser (excpet IE with above solution) supports playing WMV files. You will have to convert it into a format that browsers know how to play. A free online converter  to MP4 is 
[here](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/wmv-to-mp4/%E2%80%8E)
 and a standalone one is [here](http://www.wmvtomp4converter.org/%E2%80%8E).

Comment: Thx for the answer, but is MP4 a format the biggest four browsers(Safari, FF, IE, Chrome) know?

Comment: @SimonJensen Yes. And if you count this as the answer, please upvote and choose as answer! ;)

Comment: @SimonJensen By the way Google Chrome and Firefox do not officially support MP4, but see this interesting question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173822/chrome-could-play-html5-mp4-video-but-html5test-said-chrome-did-not-support-mp4

Comment: Just BTW, [H.264 has licencing issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Licensing).